# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot find NVidia drivers

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia-geforce

So, yesterday I went from windows to Ubuntu 18.04.
The problem is, it seems, that Ubuntu does not "accept" my Nvidia drivers.
I'm running two graphics card: Intel and Nvidia GTX1050.

I have tried almost all different approaches now:
I installed the drivers using `sudo apt-get nvidia-410`, `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, and I have tried downloading them from NVidias homepage, but now I'm simply lost.

If I call `lshw -c video` there is no driver under "configuration" for my Nvidia (there is for Intel), if i call `sudo nvidia-settings` it throws two errors:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

I have, right now, absolutely no idea what to try...

Comment: You might want to clarify what is "my Nvidia drivers". Are those personal modified, custom made drivers? How many are they? Also outputs of `ubuntu-drivers devices` or `ubuntu-drivers debug` could be useful, in case you are interested in a driver from the repositories.

Comment: Did you run sudo apt-get update at any time after the install?  That makes many more packages available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What turned out to do the trick was to disable "secure booting" then purge nvidia and reinstall it using `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.

Now it works like a charm!

Comment: I found this guy's notes for setting up nvidia drivers with secureboot on to be helpful if disabling it feels too insecure for future question readers: https://gist.github.com/bitsurgeon/b0f4440984c9e60dcd8fe8bbc346c029

Comment: This still works for Ubuntu 18.04 with Nvidia Graphics card in 2020

Answer (score 2):

Run

`software-properties-gtk`

This will open Software & Updates.

Go to Additional Drivers Check Nvidia driver and Apply Changes.

[image: Software & Updates]

Comment: That I've done after each installation (:NVIDIA can still not be found as a driver